# PinCode Null from Longitude and latitude Android Location Services

Tags: android, google-maps, geolocation

I am trying to get pincode for longitude and latitude using google location services. I used geocoder to get the Address Object. I see that in for some address `getPostalCode` is Null but postal code can be seen in the address lines.

How do I get the postal code in this case? Should i use regex to get it?

Answer (score 0):

Based from this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding#GeocodingRequests), you need to specify the restriction by using the [`componentRestrictions`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#GeocoderComponentRestrictions) parameter and can be filter by `postalCode` or `country`.

The following example function demonstrates using the `componentRestrictions` parameter to filter by `country` and `postalCode`:

```
function codeAddress() {
geocoder.geocode({
  componentRestrictions: {
    country: 'AU',
    postalCode: '2000'
  }
}, function(results, status) {
  if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
    map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      map: map,
      position: results[0].geometry.location
    });
  } else {
    window.alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
  }
});
}
```

You can check this [example](https://github.com/BTaillefer/PostalCode-Maps) in GitHub.